# Подсчет count по двум полям

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть поля:

```
IdLikeNote (100)
IdLikeType (0/1)

Нужно одним запросом подсчитать кол-во строк для `IdLikeType = 0` и `IdLikeType = 1` для записи с `IdLikeNote = 100`.
```

Comment: Только через UNION?

Comment: @IOleg, чуть элегантнее будет двумя подзапросами, но суть останется той же.

Comment: @IOleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Смотря как вам нужно посчитать эти суммы - отдельно для каждого IdLikeType:

> `SELECT IdLikeType, count(1)
> FROM temp
> where IdLikeNote = 100 and IdLikeType in (0,1)
> group by IdLiKeType;`

или общую:

> `SELECT count(1)
> FROM temp
> where IdLikeNote = 100 and IdLikeType in (0,1);`

Answer (score 2):

Так:

```
select 
  sum(if(IdLikeType=1,1,0)) as ones,
  sum(if(IdLikeType=0,1,0)) as zeros
from likers
where 
  IdLikeNote=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось что-то в роде этого:

```
select count(*) c1 from likers where IdLikeNote=1 and IdLikeType=0 group by IdLikeNote
UNION
select count(*) c1 from likers where IdLikeNote=1 and IdLikeType=1 group by IdLikeNote
```

Код на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3275b/1)